# Is there a way to properly catch exception 'org.apache.spark.sql.delta.ConcurrentAppendException' on python?

Tags: apache-spark, exception, pyspark, delta-lake

There are multiple data pipelines that can cause Concurrent Append Exception trying to update the same delta table, I'm not able to control the concurrency of those pipelines. I will like to catch the exception and retry the update of the delta table, but seems that even if I add a try and catch the exception is not being handled. Any suggestion is welcome.

```py
try:
   # Update delta, retry in case of concurrency 
   curatedTable.alias("staged").merge(updateDF.alias("curated"),
     "staged.ExperienceId = curated.ExperienceId AND staged.ExperienceVersion = curated.ExperienceVersion") \
     .whenMatchedUpdate(set = { "staged.updated" : "True" } ).execute()
   break
except exception as e:
   if retry < 2:
     continue
   else:
     raise Exception("RETRY FAILED")
```

Instead of getting the Exception with 'RETRY FAILED' message I'm getting  the following

```
Operation on target Notebook Synapse failed: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42198.save.
: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.ConcurrentAppendException: Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again.
Conflicting commit: ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export ConcurrentAppendException from delta.exceptions, then catch this exception. Works perfectly for me.